# Google Cloud Endpoint generates clashing classes in client API for Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have successfully created google cloud endpoint classes based on several classes, that have several entity relationships. From the project, I have created a google cloud endpoint library with generated packages for the individual endpoints to be used in our Android App. These endpoint packages partly contain the same classes since the underlying entity classes reference each other and the library generation seems to flatten all the dependencies of a given endpoint into on package. With that, I have several copies of the same class in different packages.

Now that I am trying to use the underlying entity models in our Android app, I have issues with these conflicting classes of one and the same entity. Essentially, within GET and PUT endpoint methods I would like to cast between these classes as they are returned or specified as parameter, which is impossible given the package hierarchies they are in.

While I can correctly call RESTful endpoint methods, I would like to know about the best paradigm to handle entity classes across our backend and our android application to avoid such conflicts of package class conflicts.